# Delete non manifold vertices

Tags: meshlab, manifold

I have a mesh (.obj) with the following `Topological Measures` via MeshLab:

```
V: 13602 E: 38706 F: 25126  
Unreferenced Vertices 0  
Boundary Edges 2034
Mesh is composed by 101 connected component(s)  
Mesh has 11 non two manifold vertices and 117 faces are incident on these vertices  
Mesh has a undefined number of holes (non 2-manifold mesh)  
Genus is undefined (non 2-manifold mesh)
```

I want to fix the holes but presume the `non manifold vertices` needs to be corrected first *---My goal is a water-tight surface (no holes / gaps) and these challenges suggest I do not have one.*

`Filters -> Selection -> non Manifold Vertices` then
`Filter -> Selection -> Delete Selected Vertices` which does:
`Deleted 11 vertices, 117 faces`

Why does it delete the incident adjacent faces?
Is it possible to / how do I delete the vertices only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete any vertex, the faces that are using that vertex are also deleted. There is no way to keep the face if you delete one of its vertices.

To solve non manifold vertex, you have to use the filter '[Repair non Manifold Vertices by splitting](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#meshing_repair_non_manifold_vertices)', which will split/duplicate non Manifold vertices until it becomes 2-Manifold.

Keep in mind that running the "[Remove duplicate vertices](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#meshing_remove_duplicate_vertices)" or "[Merge Close Vertices](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#meshing_merge_close_vertices)" filters probably will result in a non manifold surface again.